# cannot scroll on page after modal close

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, popup

i have a model to update data. and when the update button is clicked the modal closes but i can no longer scroll on the page that reloads after the closing of modal

```
$(document).off('click','.updatecat');
 $(document).on('click','.updatecat',function(){
    $('#cat-update').ajaxSubmit({ 
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            if(response.type == 'success'){
                $('#catupdate').modal('hide');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove()
                $('#taba4').trigger('click');  
            }else{
                alert(response.message);
            }
            alert("Category Updated");
            console.log(response);

        }
    })

 });
```

I have no idea why this is happening. i have implemented the same script elsewhere and i can scroll on page after modal closes. please help.

Comment: update your question with modal code

Comment: posted a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679148/cannot-csroll-on-page-after-modal-closes       here is the link to the new question

Answer (score 1):

remove below line

```
$('#catupdate').modal('hide');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove()
```

and add below line

```
if(response.type == 'success'){
   $('#catupdate').hide();
}
```

Comment: if i do that then the page will freeze. the modal closes but i cannot do anything in the page

Comment: are you using bootstrap modal?

Comment: That might be issue with your modal coding

Comment: i have used the same model and same script for another page also but there i can scroll after the modal closes.

Comment: can you try $(this).hide(); I think you are using wrong id